# Determining $\int \frac{\sec^2x-2021}{\sin^{2021}x} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

> Determine
> $$\int \frac{\sec^2x-2021}{\sin^{2021}x} dx$$

I tried dividing by $\cos^{2021}x$ in both numerator and denominator which gave me a simplified form of
$$\dfrac{\sec^{2021}x(\sec^2x-2021)}{\tan^{2021}x}$$
but that doesn't seem to help much.

Comment: What's the source of this question? The appearance of $2021$ may lead people to wonder if it's from an on-going contest.

Comment: No actually,you could replace $2021$ with $n$.

Comment: @Blue It jee advance question https://jeeadv.ac.in/pastqp.php see the maths section

Answer (score 5):

Integrating by parts
$$\int \frac{\sec^2(x)}{\sin^{n}(x)}\, dx=\frac{\tan(x)}{\sin^{n}(x)}-\int\frac{\tan(x)(-n\cos(x))}{\sin^{n+1}(x)}\,dx=\frac{\tan(x)}{\sin^{n}(x)}+\int\frac{n}{\sin^{n}(x)}\,dx.$$
Hence, after moving the remaining integral to the other side, we find
$$\int \frac{\sec^2(x)-n}{\sin^{n}(x)}\, dx=\frac{\tan(x)}{\sin^{n}(x)}+c.$$